# Как реализовать очень быстрое переключение между фрагментами android?

Tags: android, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

У меня есть родительская активность. В ней расположен контейнер и bottomNavigationView с пятью кнопками. При нажатии на кнопки я замещаю текущий фрагмент выбранным. В чем проблема: при супер быстром нажатии на кнопки нижней менюшки у меня отображается неправильное содержимое в тулбаре (title+subtitle+menu). Думал проверять видимый ли фрагмент и тогда уже грузить данные, но так не получилось. Дальше думал проверять в самом фрагменте видимость фрагмента, но так тоже не получилось сделать. Дальше я вот читаю что можно решить проблему как-то через `show` а не `replace` при транзакции фрагмента. Я вот проверил сейчас некоторые приложения и там все работает нормально и без проблем. Вот слушатель нажатий на нижний bottomNavigationView:
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =

```
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.full_jobAgent -> {

                position = 4
                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.show()
                Singleton.filter_data = HashMap()
                val jobList = JobsList()
                bundle.putInt("offset", 1)

                if (intent.getSerializableExtra("filter_data") != null) {
                    bundle.putSerializable("filter_data", intent.getSerializableExtra("filter_data"))
                }
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, jobList).addToBackStack(null).commit()

                if(jobList.isVisible){
                    Log.i("m","1")
                }else{
                    Log.i("m","2")
                }


                textSetter("Jobagent", resources.getString(R.string.all_jobs) + " " + sp!!.getString("all_jobs", ""))
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.received_mess -> {
                position = 0
                bottom_navigation_t.menu.findItem(R.id.received_mess).title.chunked(1)
                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.show()
                val messageList = MessagesList()
                bundle.putInt("type1", 0)
                messageList.arguments = bundle
                textSetter(resources.getString(R.string.title_activity_message_center), resources.getString(R.string.received))
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, messageList).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.home_screen -> {
                position = 3
                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.hide()
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, PersonalPage()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.notespec -> {
                position = 4
                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.show()
                val notepadScr = NotepadScr()
                if (intent.getSerializableExtra("filter_data") != null) {
                    bundle.putSerializable("filter_data", intent.getSerializableExtra("filter_data"))
                } else {
                    val filters = HashMap<String, String>()
                    filters["archive"] = 0.toString()
                    filters["added_type"] = 1.toString()
                    bundle.putSerializable("filter_data", filters)
                }
                bundle.putInt("offset", 1)
                notepadScr.arguments = bundle

                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, notepadScr).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.more -> {
                position = 6
                disableShowHideAnimation(supportActionBar!!)
                supportActionBar!!.hide()
                textSetter(resources.getString(R.string.more_bottom_nav), "")
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainerT, MoreScreenK()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

Так же были проблемы с тем что возникали ошибки когда программа не могла найти пункт меню тулбара, но я убрал эти ошибки путем добавления проверки на null. Ничего не могу придумать как решить эту проблему. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и у него есть решение?

Comment: Возможно вы не так проверяли из фрагмента видим ли он в данный момент? У меня, вроде, вот в этом методе манипуляции с `Toolbar` нормально проходили: `public void setUserVisibleHint(final boolean isVisibleToUser)`

Comment: Ну и да, чтобы для юезра всё выглядело быстро, фрагменты надо не заменять, но скрывать/показывать. Так не будет дёрганий и подвисаний при переключении. Но вылезет много других проблем, правда)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вот вы метод упоминали - это встроенный функционал, или ваш? и что вы имели в виду когда сказали скрывать/показывать фрагменты, и о каких проблемах идет речь? Я вот сейчас пробовал использовать hide/show (возможно это то что вы имели в виду) , но у меня контент фрагмента не показывается вообще, я так и не понял в чем проблема)

Comment: Метод `setUserVisibleHint()` - это метод фрагмента, его можно в своих фрагментах переопределить. По второму - да, `hide/show` вместо `replace`. Сложности тут могут быть разные. Т.к. фрагмент не окончательно выгружается из памяти, то, если их много и они тяжёлые, то может память кончиться. Если вы что-то там завязываете на методы жизненного цикла, то надо очень внимательно изучить отличие последовательности вызова оных в отличие от `replace`, чтобы не получить лишних/не случившихся попыток загрузки данных, активации либ и прочая и прочая.

Comment: вот у меня получилось через add/show/hide сделать, но все-равно при супер быстром переключении у меня подгружается неправильные данные в тулбар и в этом собственно и вся проблема :(

Comment: Ну да, `add/show/hide` к тулбару не относятся, скорее к отзывчивости интерфейса. А тулбар попробуйте через setUserVisibleHint сделать.

Comment: так а как его сделать-то я никак не могу понять, чем именно мне эта функция поможет? я вот доки читаю, и вот что читаю - `Set a hint to the system about whether this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user. This hint defaults to true and is persistent across fragment instance state save and restore` но так и не понял где именно эту функцию использовать, по факту у меня проблема в том что тулбар не отображает данные которые принадлежат нужному фрагменту.

Comment: У меня как-то так работает: в методе сём, если активити не null, и значение аргумента - true, то получаю из активити тулбар и устанавливаю ему заголовок.

Comment: то есть насколько я понимаю вы устанавливаете заголовок из самого фрагмента, вопрос - как вы передаете значение тулбару который в активности, интерфейсы используете? и что за аргумент значение которого тру?

Comment: Да, интерфейс как-то используется. Аргумент метода setUserVisibleHint

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в целом понятно что ничего не понятно))) буду разбираться, спасибо что задали вектор движения :)